# Visually Impaired guide to gnome

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I am a  Linux user from years back(when fedora was called RedHat). I stepped away from Linux for quite a few years because time did not permit me to learn two systems. I recently became disabled and now have nothing but time. I decided to try Linux again as I heard it had come a long way with accessibility. I am blind but thought I would try it out. I have been able to get most things up and running fairly well.

This is where I am having problems. I installed Ubuntu-gnome as I have found gnome to be more accessible than Unity. It is installed on my laptop in an encrypted volume. My problems are from the login. With some sited assistance I have figured out how to get to the login screen, but have problems logging in. From what I am told, it appears to be a command line login. I installed speakup to try to access it but could not get it to work. It will start speaking but just reads off a few lines and stops. It says something about trying to connect to pulse audio and then tries to connect to a few other similar things before it stops speaking. I think it is just because speakup needs to be configured, but I can not figure out how to do that.

I guess the heart of my question is this:

A. What would be the easiest way to setup an accessible login to Ubuntu-GNOME?
B. If it is speakup, how do I set that up?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: If you only get the command line the system might be broken, so maybe nothing to read but those few lines displayed.

Comment: OK. The system is not broken. With a little help, I can login. My problem is figuring out how to make the login accessible. I know that unity login was accessible, so I figured that gnome had to have some way to make their login accessible too.

Comment: Try switching to lightdm if it is better,  http://askubuntu.com/a/58549/47291

Answer (score 1):

OK. After a few days of research I found the answer. I enabled the screen reader for the install from the live DVD. It did not, however, enable all the accessibility features like a normal ubuntu install does. It was starting GDM but just wasn't talking to me. I just needed to use the Ubuntu screen reader hot keys to get it to talk on login from that point on. Just press Super(Windows)+alt+S and the screen reader will start on the login screen.