# Which display manager should I choose when installing Gnome 3

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, gdm, display-manager, sddm

When I was trying to install Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 16.04, just to get an experience, I got the below message. That dilemma forced me to search the site and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58528/whats-the-difference-between-gdm-and-lightdm) and many others.Which display manager should I choose here? Is there a problem if I choose lightdm or sddm when installing Gnome?

[image]

Comment: The most common display managers for desktop environments are as follows: LightDM => Unity, Xfce, Lmde, Budgie. SDDM => Plasma 5. GDM3 => Gnome3

Answer (score 3):

The display manager is the program which displays the graphical login page. In practice there is very little to chose, they all let you chose a username and enter a password, and possibly choose what kind of graphical session to run. `lightdm` is the default display manager which comes with Ubuntu. `gdm3`, the Gnome Display Manager, is the default display manager for the Gnome desktop.

See [What is gdm3, kdm, lightdm? How to install and remove them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them).